# Infinite loop when calculating recursive sum

Tags: c++, recursion, sum

this function is supposed to calculate the sum inclusive ie. sum(2, 5) should yield 2 + 3 + 4 + 5.

```
int sum(int m, int n) {
    if (m != n) {
        return m + sum(m++, n);
    }
    return n;
}
```

However, i get a run time error every time i run this code.

Comment: What do you think that `sum(m++, n);` does?

Comment: What is your error? Please include that in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m++` returns the value of `m` before incrementing, so it will infinitely recurse. You should call `sum(m + 1, n)` instead. Also, you should consider changing `m != n` to `m < n` to prevent the case of `m > n` from recursing infinitely.

Comment: and maybe catch the case of `m > n`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `++m` just wastes time incrementing m when it's not used anywhere else in the function

Comment: @Aplet123 The entire code wastes time. Could just compute it in one go: `int sum(int m, int n) { return (std::abs(m - n) + 1) * (m + n) / 2; }`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca `m + sum(m++, n);` is undefined behaviour till C++14, it reads and modifies `m` unsequenced.

Comment: @rustyx while this is true I'm also assuming that this is probably for some exercise in recursion and thus can not be reduced to a single formula

Comment: @rustyx if you write the same as a loop, compilers I checked are clever enough to avoid the loop and spit out the result directly (using the formula you quote), didnt try if it also works with a recursion tough

Answer (score 0):

Don't increment m while calling, instead pass `m+1`

```
int sum(int m, int n)
{
    if(m != n)
        return m + sum(m+1, n);
    return m;
}
```